# create a new postgres table but with averages

Tags: postgresql

I'm a SQL newbie.

I have a postgres table that has datetime, and values. with subminute entries. I want to create a new table that takes the average of each minute and saves that instead of having subminute entries. so something like this:

```
1-12-07 12:29:56:00   2
1-12-07 12:29:56:16   3
1-12-07 12:29:56:34   3
1-12-07 12:29:56:58   4
1-12-07 12:30:00:00   7
```

to

```
1-12-07 12:29:00   3
1-12-07 12:30:00   #
```

Is there a way to do it in postgres?

The only solution I can think of is using a python script to do the trick. But that will take forever as I have a significant amount of data.

Comment: what do you mean by "the average of each minute"

Comment: the first table has four entries for 12:29 and the table below only has 1 entry for 12:29 which sums up all four entries at 12:29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this you must group the results by your time truncated at the minutes:

```
insert into "NewTable"
select minute, avg(value) from (select date_trunc('minutes', date) as minute, value from "Time") as Average group by minute;
```

Comment: This looks like the right approach. The select function seems to be correct but the insertion doesn't work. This is probably because I didn't give you all the columns. So here it is I want to go from

name, date, time, value, size 

to

name, date, time, avg(value), sum(size)

any suggestions?

Comment: In this case I would suggest that you use only one field for date and time. You can bring any field from the former table, but other than date it needs to be included on the group by:

`insert into "NewTable" (name, date, value, size)`
`select name, minute, avg(value), count(*) from (select name, date_trunc('minutes', date) as minute, value from "Time") as Average group by name, minute;`

Comment: close but not excatly yet.

Comment: select symbol, date, time, avg(price), sum(size) from (select symbol, date, date_trunc('minutes', time) as time, price, size from ALU) as Average group by symbol, date, time, size;

Comment: You never defined "size" at your question so I assumed you wanted to know the time entry count, but if "size" is actually another field it must have its own aggregate function or be on group by, not both. Your select must be:

`select symbol, date, time, avg(price), sum(size) from (select symbol, date, date_trunc('minutes', time) as time, price, size from ALU) as Average group by symbol, date, time;`

Answer (score 0):

So this is going to be awful and inefficient and an incomplete answer, recommend writing a script (just my .02)

It should be something like this, since there is not a sqlFiddle provided in the question:

```
select average(my_count)
   from
   (
      select my_date, my_time,my_count 
      from my_table
      group by my_date, extract(minute from my_time)
   )
```